# ESENT Warnings in Logs

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012, esent

We have a Windows 2012 database server hosting SQL server 2012 and recently we have found numerous "ESENT" warnings in the Applications log, usually before 9 am in the morning.  The ESENT codes are 531, 910, 509, 510, 533 and 507 but each code does not have the same message details and so too many to list here.  But some state that they are Database Page Cache warnings and involve the Healthservicestore.edb  and current.mdb files.  It appears the ESENT is the "embeddable database engine native to Windows" is this correct? If so what will the SQL Server database be doing with it? And what are the Healthservicestore.edb  and current.mdb files? So far I have found little on Google about them

Answer (score 0):

Well, the HealthServiceStore.edb is indeed an ESE database.... but it has nothing to do with SQL Server

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jimmyharper/2015/09/02/management-pack-to-monitor-and-reduce-health-service-store-size/